# How to ingest JSON from TXT file?

Tags: json, postgresql, data-ingestion

The problem is not to get TXT because it is

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(file_get_contents('/tmp/test.json'))
```

returns not a JSON object but a string...  Even with `replace(txt,E'\n',' ')` it not works. How to normalize and really convert string to JSON?

PS: I am using JSONb that must be some thing as JSON for ingestion.

---

### NOTES

The json file `/tmp/test.json`:

```
[
    {
      "foo": "etc",
      "bar": "etc",
      "x": 123
    },
    {
      "foo": "aaa",
      "bar": "bbb",
      "x": 456
    }
]
```

I am using UBUNTU 18 LTS, PostgreSQL v12 and file in linux standard TXT. Termial command `file -i /tmp/test.json` say that is all good, "text/plain; charset=utf-8".

To load full-text into only one field (seems impossible with COPY FROM), PostgreSQL is ugly, but this function was tested and is reliable:

```
CREATE EXTENSION PLpython3U;
CREATE or replace FUNCTION file_get_contents(p_file text) RETURNS text AS $$
   import os.path
   if not os.path.isfile(args[0]):
       return None
   with open(args[0],"r") as content_file:
       content = content_file.read()
   return content
$$ LANGUAGE PLpython3U;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using postgresql, I saved your file on my `/tmp` directory.

To read the file, if the file is on your postgresql server, you can use `pg_read_file()`.

To simulate your scenario I tried the following:

**APPROACH 1 (`json_array_elements_text`):**

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(
       REPLACE(PG_READ_FILE('/tmp/teste.txt'), E'\n', '')::JSON);
```

This series of functions is very similar that you used, except by the `pg_read_file` that reads file on server and `json_array_elements_text`.

The result is:

```
                  json_array_elements_text                  
------------------------------------------------------------
 {      "foo": "etc",      "bar": "etc",      "x": 123    }
 {      "foo": "aaa",      "bar": "bbb",      "x": 456    }
(2 rows)
```

**APPROACH 2 (`json_to_recordset`):**

```
select * from json_to_recordset(replace(pg_read_file('/tmp/teste.txt'), E'\n', '')::json) as ("foo" varchar, "bar" varchar, "x" int);
 foo | bar |  x  
-----+-----+-----
 etc | etc | 123
 aaa | bbb | 456
(2 rows)
```

The result is similar than the first example but, in this approach we define columns based on elements found on original json data

Comment: Thanks @William. The @jjanes answer is better to read, but you was the first and show the `PG_READ_FILE()` that seems good and more reliable tham a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

It is already in a JSON format you just have to cast it:

```
SELECT file_get_contents('/tmp/test.json')::jsonb
```

The docs for "to_json" say

> For any scalar type other than a number, a Boolean, or a null value,
>   the text representation will be used, in such a fashion that it is a
>   valid json or jsonb value.

In other words, it does the escaping and quoting necessary to turn your file into a single JSON value.  Not a JSON object, just a single value.  So "to_json" is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks, is it. But original file is not in "all in one line" JSON... This is the big problem, and there are no internal PostgreSQL tool to sanitize lines and spaces (exist?)... I am using terminal `jq --compact-output  . original.json > sanitized.json`

Comment: Is this an OS specific problem?  For me, it just works, on Linux.  If the whitespace is not significant (i.e. outside of quotes) it just gets ignored.