# Issue while exporting geojson data to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geojson

I am trying to export `geojson` data into a table in PostgreSQL. I have multiple `geojson` files in a `directory` passed as input to PostgreSQL function. I loop over all the filenames in that directory and then read file data using `pg_read_file` and then try to build `geojson_data` object which I can then use to insert values in the table.

The `plpgsql` function I have written is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_geojson_data(directory text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    file_name text;
    geojson_data json;
begin
    -- Loop through GeoJSON files in the specified directory
    FOR file_name IN 
        SELECT *
        FROM pg_ls_dir(directory)
    loop
        -- Read GeoJSON data from file
        IF file_name LIKE '%.geojson' then
       
        RAISE NOTICE 'GeoJSON data: %', pg_read_file(directory || '/' || file_name);
        EXECUTE 'SELECT jsonb_agg(features) FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(($1::jsonb)->>''features'')'
            INTO geojson_data
            USING pg_read_file(directory || '/' || file_name);

        -- Insert data into the states table
        INSERT INTO states (shapeId, name, geometry)
        select
            geojson_data->>'properties'->>'shapeId',
            geojson_data->>'properties'->>'name',
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_data->>'geometry');
           
        RAISE NOTICE 'Data from % inserted successfully', file_name;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now, when I execute the function with a path of directory:
`SELECT public.insert_geojson_data('path/to/directory');`

I have put a
`RAISE NOTICE 'GeoJSON data: %', pg_read_file(directory || '/' || file_name);`
which prints fine as below:

```
GeoJSON data: {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "crs": {
          "type": "name",
          "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
          }
        },
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [95.23729640200742, 26.679843368876448],
            [95.2356467872695, 26.68178477135018],
            [95.23566295528121, 26.68507127991569],
            [95.2504579873463, 26.685907840974153],
            [95.24362625324903, 26.687443945981386],
            [95.24011046522583, 26.685192466259366],
            [95.23729640200742, 26.679843368876448]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "shapeId": "fc13a047-aaac-4e9e-ba39-5544f0ffb21c",
        "type": "State",
        "iso_group": "IND",
        "name": "Arunanchal Pradesh",
        "admin_level": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But after that I get an **error**

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements_text(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function insert_geojson_data(text) line 15 at EXECUTE
```

Seems the problem lies somewhere in the below code, and I am not able to figure that out, would appreciate some help here. Thanks!

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT jsonb_agg(features) FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(($1::jsonb)->>''features'')'
            INTO geojson_data
            USING pg_read_file(directory || '/' || file_name);
```

Comment: Does this link help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163760/how-to-ingest-json-from-txt-file can it be that your JSON line breaks are an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `->>` operator you're using converts the property value to `text`, which is not what you want. Use `->` instead, which returns a value of type `json(b)`.

Btw there's no reason to `EXECUTE` dynamic SQL in your function:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(features) INTO geojson_data
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text((pg_read_file(directory || '/' || file_name)::jsonb)->'features');
```

You later have the same issue in your `INSERT` query - use `->>` only for the last property access, or use a single `#>>` expression.

Another issue you haven't encountered yet is that `geojson_data` will contain an array, so you cannot access a property on that, you first need to extract all (or only the first?) elements from the array:

```
-- Insert data into the states table
INSERT INTO states (shapeId, name, geometry)
SELECT el->'properties'->>'shapeId', el->'properties'->>'name', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_data->'geometry')
FROM json_array_elements(geojson_data) AS el;
```

Although probably it makes sense not to store the JSON data in a temporary variable at all - insert it directly while reading from the file:

```
INSERT INTO states (shapeId, name, geometry)
SELECT el->'properties'->>'shapeId', el->'properties'->>'name', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_data->'geometry')
FROM jsonb_array_elements((pg_read_file(directory || '/' || file_name)::jsonb)->'features') AS features(el)
```

Oh, and use `jsonb_array_elements` not `jsonb_array_elements_text`.